Coroutine function generic type alias
I'm trying to achieve a typing shorthand for coroutines just like basic callables like Callable[[..args..], ..return value..]
My idea is to write something like that, but in the attempt, I cannot understand how TypeAlias would later match where the P, and where the RV...
P = ParamSpec('P')
RV = TypeVar('RV')

CoroutineFunction: TypeAlias = Callable[P, Awaitable[RV]]

Then, I want to use it as follows
# this is just sample coroutine
async def my_afunc(a: int, b: str) -> bool:
    return bool(a or b)

# this is usage example
def some_decorator(afunc: CoroutineFunction[[int, str], bool]):
    ...

# this should handle type checking correctly, 
# and warn me if I change the return value type for my_afunc
smth = some_decorator(my_afunc)
    

I'm using python 3.11, but 3.12 ideas are also appreciable.

What you have here is correct. If you want to know how type arguments are substituted in type aliases, that's too broad of a question - all the information with examples should be in here: https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/generics.html. A rough summary is: "Look at the type alias expression from left-to-right. For every free type-variable-like (Here, P and RV), expect the type alias to accept arguments from left-to-right in the same order". P is substituted by [<type list>], ellipsis ... or another ParamSpec, and RV is substituted by a type or "normal" type variable.

@dROOOze this probably should be posted as answer, thank you. But my type checker (pycharm) still does not validate anything in the case. I haven't tested it with mypy yet, though.

PyCharm's static analysis is lacking compared to mypy and pyright. If you want to quickly validate something, use the mypy Playground or Pyright Plagyround. Otherwise, there are 2 mypy plugins and 1 Pyright plugin for IntelliJ IDEs that you can download from the marketplace for PyCharm.
